# Can I use WebHDFS in Azure HDInsight?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I have created a HDInisght with Azure Storage as its HDFS. And I wana to know whether I can use webHDFS apis to upload binaries to HDFS.

I tried `https://<HOST>:<HTTP_PORT>/webhdfs/v1/`. But I am not sure of the `Host` and `Http_port`.

Meanwhile, I checked the `hdfs-site.xml` and found

```
  <property>
    <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
```

Should I set the value to `True` and then I can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note:** Azure HDInsight does not support WebHDFS.

You do not need to create an HDInsight cluster to talk to ADLS using WebHDFS.

1. Azure Storage is not WebHDFS compatible.
2. Azure Data Lake Store is a cloud-scale file system that is compatible with Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) and works with the Hadoop ecosystem. Your existing applications or services that use the WebHDFS API can easily integrate with ADLS.

[image]

**Reference:** [WebHDFS FileSystem APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datalakestore/webhdfs-filesystem-apis)

3. ADLS Gen2 is Hadoop Filesystem compatible and optimized for a cloud scale big data analytics storage and is not WebHDFS compatible.